# Highcharts Booster not working in Styled Mode

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-boost

I am using Highcharts version 5 in styled mode and now have the need to integrate the boost module.

Two questions arise:

1. In [this article](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/news/higcharts-boost-module/) it says that

> "with the release of Highcharts 6 the boost module has gotten a
>   facelift, and has officially graduated from “experimental” to a
>   fully-fledged module"

Does the activation of boost.js require an update from version 5 to 6?

2. The boost module seems not to be compatible with styled mode.
   As you see in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/43s6xgwc/23/), in styled mode once the booster kicks in, the series is not displayed anymore (though it seems to be displayed transparently, as the tooltips still work).

So this code

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/boost.js"></script>

...

  Highcharts.chart('container', {
      boost: {
          enabled : true
      },
      series: [{
          data: [...]
      }]
  });
```

renders to this:

[image]

Whereas this code

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/boost.js"></script>

...

  Highcharts.chart('container', {
      boost: {
          enabled : false
      },
      series: [{
          data: [...]
      }]
  });
```

Renders correctly to this:
[image]

Please note that both examples differ in enabling the boost module and styled mode is activated by importing highcharts from /**js**/highcharts.js path.

Is there any way to use the booster without having to refactor my whole code to non-styled mode?

Answer (score 0):

**1.**
**No**. Boost was available in Highcharts versions prior to 6 - it was experimental. Always make sure that **Highcharts** and **boost** module are the same version e.g.:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/5.0.5/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/5.0.5/modules/boost.js"></script>
```

Keep in mind that it's recommended to use the latest version of the library.

---

**2.** 
Series are generated as an **image** by WebGL engine while using boost module - it's not possible to style its elements via CSS.

[image: Series generated in webgl in developer console]

Comment: I get that you cannot use css to style the image, but does boost fall back to the color options? I am trying to make sure that my styles are reflected both in boost and non-boost while using style mode.

Comment: Boost module has some limitations e.g. it doesn't suport individual color for points. This topic is discussed here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5999 What exactly are you trying to achieve?